# How To Create A Menu With Images and Pages, Like iPod Menu

Tags: xcode, menu, popover

I'm trying to find a tutorial or book, that explain who to make a menu application, like the iPod/iPad menu, with images as buttons, and pages. What i'm trying to do, is a menu, with a Popover window, when an option from the popover is selected, then the menu is filled (with code) with the buttons/images, that can be located in more then a page.
Thanks you in advance

Comment: Are you meaning something along the lines of the springboard application?

Comment: yeah, something like this: http://www.redrome.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/iphone_4_springboard_screenshot.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there are two things you can use here:

The Three20 library , which has several extra components you can use as well: [repository here](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

If you want just a view similar to that and nothing else, you can go with myLauncher: [repository here](https://github.com/Jarada/myLauncher)

I know there are probably more, but these were the main two I looked at when I went looking for a similar view.

Comment: Oh, Thank You Very Much! I really appreciate your help. I had liked, to make the menu (add the images, buttons, pages, etc)on my own, but I guess is a lot of work.

Comment: You can still, When I used the myLauncher stuff, I had to edit out a lot, and you might have to make your own changes to it to make it work with a popover.  I don't know too much about the Three20, but the myLauncher has a google groups page where you can ask for help at.

Comment: I was checking Three20, but I guess, myLauncher it's more like what i want. Thank you very much, you have given me hope in the middle of my frustration as a app developer beginner haha. Regards

Comment: One more question, if i use myLauncher, App Store can reject my app for use it?

Comment: Mine got approved and it uses it.

Comment: Hi, me again... I'm trying to add MyLauncher to my project, but I get lost. Can I add the menu options above my UIImageView? Because I have a background image, and two toolbars?

Comment: You mean the name of the icon above the image? You can, just have to figure out how to rearrange the view to make it fit.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Jost one more doubt. Can I change the icons size, image and position? I mean, can I locate just 3 items, in the positions that i want?